# MPLAX X IDE v5.40 won´t start

Tags: macos, microchip

I am using macOs Catalina, previously I had been using MPLAP X IDE v5.40 (the most recent) with no problems. 
Yesterday I tried to open the app but the screen goes black, then recover its previous state and the icon (just the icon not the splash screen) appears in the dock then after 2 -3 seconds the screen goes black again and the icon disappear. I thoght I have a corrupted installation but I already unistalled and reinstalled both java and the MPLAB with no success. 
I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can often correct a bunch of these problems by deleting the cache, and if that doesn't work, delete the user directory.

To find  their locations, go to the Help/About dialog box.

Deleting the cache usually just means that startup may be a little slower. Deleting the user directory means you will lose your setting, so MPLAB will start as a new installation and perhaps will ask you if you want to import the settings from an older version;